# Spring Boot programmatically restart app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a Spring Boot app, in which I need to write Java code to shut down the app itself (including its threads), and then restart it. I've tried the following two methods, the first one is to issue a Linux command in Java like the following:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -SIGINT " + pid);
```

where pid is that of the app itself. This has the same effect as pressing `"ctrl + c"`. But having shut down the app successfully this way, I don't know how I can restart it. I tried to issue another command (like "`mvn spring-boot:run`", which is how I start the app) using the same method but since the app is shut down already, this doesn't work.

Secondly, I've also tried calling the `refresh()` method of AbstractApplicationContext as follows:

```
AbstractApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
appContext.registerShutdownHook();
appContext.refresh();
```

But I don't think this kind of context refreshing is the same as restarting?

So what is the proper way to restart a Spring Boot app with Java code? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't think that there is a proper way to restart Spring boot app with Java code. Why not shell script instead. Also Server side applications should be designed in a way that allows them to run for a long time.

Answer (score 4):

The gstackoverflow's answer didn't work for me, my solution:

Add dependencies to build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
```

Autowired RestartEndpoint

```
@Autowired
private RestartEndpoint restartEndpoint;
```

Add this to application.properties

```
management.endpoint.restart.enabled = true
```

And invoke

```
    Thread restartThread = new Thread(() -> restartEndpoint.restart());
    restartThread.setDaemon(false);
    restartThread.start();
```

Comment: No need to invoke method via new thread, because the function restart() already create a new thread for that just like you did.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `spring-boot-starter-actuator` and `Spring cloud` dependencies to your application and use `/restart` endpoint to restart the app. [Here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html) is the documentation:

> For a Spring Boot Actuator application there are some
>   additional management endpoints:
>
> - POST to /env to update the Environment and rebind
>     @ConfigurationProperties and log levels
> - /refresh for re-loading the boot strap context and refreshing the
>     @RefreshScope beans
> - /restart for closing the ApplicationContext and restarting it
>     (disabled by default)
> - /pause and /resume for calling the Lifecycle methods (stop() and
>     start() on the ApplicationContext)

Once done, you can use a `REST API` call to restart the application (via `RestTemplate` or `curl`). This will be cleaner way to restart the app than killing it and re-running it.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on how to use RestTemplate to send a valid POST request to /restart? I tried to use postForObject("/restart", null, String.class) method with RestTemplate, but got a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute" exception. I'm new to Spring Boot. Thanks.

Comment: `curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/project-code/restart` or `restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/project-code/restart", null, String.class)` `project-code` is depedded on your configuration `server.servlet.context-path=project-code`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing only kill command, execute an already prepared script/program that kills the calling process and starts a new instance of the application.

Answer (score 0):

DevTools relies on the application context’s shutdown hook to close it during a restart. It will not work correctly if you have disabled the shutdown hook via `SpringApplication.setRegisterShutdownHook(false)`.

Also see: [Using Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html).

Answer (score 0):

Addition to [Darshan Mehta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45074749/2674303) answer:

In  my case I did this:

**1.added dependecies:**

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:1.2.4.RELEASE")
```

**2.autowired restartEndpoint:**

```
import org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartEndpoint;
....
@Autowired
private RestartEndpoint restartEndpoint;
```

**3. and invoke:**

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        restartEndpoint.invoke();
    }
});
thread.setDaemon(false);
thread.start();
```

I need new Thread because spring mvc creates daemon threads for each request

Answer (score 0):

We can use Restarter of Spring Devtools like this:

```
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.getInstance().restart()
```