# Change default Port of Spring Boot application from frontend with thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is it possible to change the spring boot port from the frontend (by using thymeleaf) over a Endpoint on a @Controller?

And how can i programatically restart the application with the new configured port?

Comment: you want to change server port?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you want to do this?

Comment: the application should run alongside several applications on one server. Port conflicts should be excluded. The User should configure the application port onthe frontend.

Comment: @SyedMustafaHussain - Yes I want to change the server port programmtically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://javahungry.blogspot.com/2019/09/change-default-port-of-spring-boot.html), you can set the server port like this:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.ConfigurableWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component; 

@Component
public class AppCustomContainer 
  implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableWebServerFactory> {

  @Override
  public void customize(ConfigurableWebServerFactory factory) {
  
   factory.setPort(1234);
  
  }
}
```

Instead of 1234, you can use a file to store the port (when changing it) and load it when starting

After that, you can restart the application as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51380374/10871900):

- Add actuator and spring-cloud:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

- Enable restarting in the `application.properties`: `management.endpoint.restart.enabled = true`
- Add an the instance of `RestartEndpoint`:

```java
@Autowired
private RestartEndpoint restartEndpoint;
```

And run this in order to restart:

```
Thread restartThread = new Thread(restartEndpoint::restart);
restartThread.setDaemon(false);
restartThread.start();
```

Comment: Don't create threads yourself, that will eventually blow up.

Comment: I think that the thread should terminate after restarting but I just copied it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51380374/10871900) as I stated in my answer.